Collect triples from Wikidata using SPARQL
I would like to collect triples (subject, predict, object) from a Wikidata entity (e.g. Helen Keller). Currently, I have a query as below:
SELECT ?wd ?wdLabel ?ps_Label ?ps_Description WHERE {     
  VALUES (?item) {(wd:Q38203)}    
  ?item ?p ?statement .   
  ?statement ?ps ?ps_ .    
  ?wd wikibase:claim ?p.   
  ?wd wikibase:statementProperty ?ps.   
  SERVICE wikibase:label {          
    bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en".    
  }         
}

I have two questions about this:

It seems that many meaningless triples will also be listed, such as properties ("CONOR.BG ID", "National Library of Ireland ID"). But all I want is the crucial triples. Can I filter them directly, or is there a score I can rank?

The above query retrieving triples seems the entity acts as a subject, not an object. In other words, the format (Helen Keller, ?, ?) can be retrieved, not (?, ?, Helen Keller). But I intend to collect all triples even though it is an object entity.




What do you mean by "meaningless"? What are your criteria? If you just want to exclude identifiers, you can add the constraint FILTER NOT EXISTS {  ?wd wdt:P31/wdt:P279* wd:Q6545185 . }



I would suggest to just do another query swapping ?item and ?ps_. In case you want to achieve this with a single query, you can replace ?item ?p ?statement . ?statement ?ps ?ps_ . with { ?item ?p ?statement . ?statement ?ps ?ps_ . } UNION {?subj ?p ?statement . ?statement ?ps ?item .} and also select ?subj in order to mark the tuples referring to the "inverted" relation.



If you just want to exclude identifiers, you can add the constraint:

FILTER NOT EXISTS {
     ?wd wdt:P31/wdt:P279* wd:Q6545185 .
}

this is excluding all the properties that are instances of (subclasses of) unique identifier (Q6545185)

I would suggest you to just do another query swapping ?item and ?ps_. In case you want to achieve this with a single query, you can replace

   ?item ?p ?statement .
   ?statement ?ps ?ps_ .

with
   { ?item ?p ?statement .
     ?statement ?ps ?ps_ . }
   UNION
   { ?subj ?p ?statement .
     ?statement ?ps ?item . }

and also select ?subj in order to mark the tuples referring to the "inverted" relation.
The resulting query would be as follows:
SELECT ?subj ?subjLabel ?subjDescription ?wd ?wdLabel ?ps_Label ?ps_Description WHERE {     
  VALUES (?item) {(wd:Q38203)}    
  { ?item ?p ?statement .
    ?statement ?ps ?ps_ . }
  UNION
  { ?subj ?p ?statement .
    ?statement ?ps ?item . }
  ?wd wikibase:claim ?p.   
  ?wd wikibase:statementProperty ?ps.   
  SERVICE wikibase:label {          
    bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en".    
  }
  FILTER NOT EXISTS {
    ?wd wdt:P31/wdt:P279* wd:Q6545185 .
  }
}
ORDER BY ?subj ?wd

